# JavaScript: Using `this` with prototype and arrow functions in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a simple prototypal inheritance constructor, which I'm using arrow functions for.

```
app.Node = function (name, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.children = [];
}

app.Node.prototype = {
    addChild: (child)=>{
        child._parent = this;
        this.children.push(child);
    },
    removeChild: (child)=>{
        this.children.forEach((item, i) => {
            if (item === child) {
                this.removeChildAtIndex(i);
            }
        });
    },
}
```

However, due to the nature of `this` and arrow functions, the value of `this` is `undefined` within the prototype methods above. So am I able to use arrow functions in this way? I can't figure out what I'd need to change, other than to use normal `function` functions.

Comment: You nailed the difference between arrow and normal functions pretty well. Arrow functions aren't just shortcuts. In your particular case a shortcut for method can be used instead, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions

Answer (score 2):

> So am I able to use arrow functions in this way?

No. Arrow functions capture the value of `this` from when they are declared.

> I can't figure out what I'd need to change, other than to use normal function functions.

Do that. Use the right tool for the job.